# To cover the edges of $5 \times 5$ grid graph with $5$ paths of $8$ edges each.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Consider the grid graph $5 \times 5$ with $25$ vertices and $40$ edges.

$1.$ cover its edges with $8$ paths of $5$ edges each.

$2.$ cover its edges with $5$ paths of $8$ edges each.

---

I am able to do the first part. But not able to do the 2nd part.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It cannot be done, since $8\times 5=40$ no edge can be repeated. Notice that each of the $12$ vertices with an odd degree must be the endpoint of at least one of those paths, however there are $10$ endpoints for the $5$ paths.